# R: na.locf to fill timeSeries/xts respecting leading and trailing NA

Tags: r, xts, fill, na, locf

First the solution I created - I am a newby so all help to improve my function is welcome:

```
library(xts)
library(timeSeries)



#' Fills the gaps of timeseries (timeSeries, xts) - ignores trailing and leading NAs.
#'
#' Suppose a timeseries object that looks as follows:
#'
#' 2017-01-01    1   10   NA    NA     NA  100000  1000000        NA
#' 2017-01-02    2   NA  200  2000  20000  200000  2000000        NA
#' 2017-01-03    3   NA  300  3000     NA      NA  3000000  30000000
#' 2017-01-04    4   40  400  4000  40000  400000  4000000        NA
#' 2017-01-05    5   50  500    NA     NA      NA       NA        NA
#'
#' Leading and trailing NAs will stay in place, whereas NAs
#' within the "data section" should be written forward (na.locf). 
#' The result of the function call would be:
#'
#' 2017-01-01    1   10   NA    NA     NA  100000  1000000        NA
#' 2017-01-02    2   10  200  2000  20000  200000  2000000        NA
#' 2017-01-03    3   10  300  3000  20000  200000  3000000  30000000
#' 2017-01-04    4   40  400  4000  40000  400000  4000000        NA
#' 2017-01-05    5   50  500    NA     NA      NA       NA        NA
#'
#' @param ts_obj xts or timeSeries object to fill
#'
#' @return timeSeries, xts - depending on handed in type
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' library(xts)
#' library(timeSeries)
#' test_matrix <- cbind(
#' c(       1,        2,        3,        4,        5),
#' c(      10,       NA,       NA,       40,       50),
#' c(      NA,      200,      300,      400,      500),
#' c(      NA,     2000,     3000,     4000,       NA),
#' c(      NA,    20000,       NA,    40000,       NA),
#' c(  100000,   200000,       NA,   400000,       NA),
#' c( 1000000,  2000000,  3000000,  4000000,       NA),
#' c(      NA,       NA, 30000000,       NA,       NA)
#' )
#' dates <- as.Date('2017-01-01') + 0:4
#' test_xts <- xts(test_matrix, dates)
#' print(test_xts)
#' print(fill_ts(test_xts))
#'
#' test_ts = as.timeSeries(test_xts)
#' print(fill_ts(test_ts))
fill_ts <- function(ts_obj) {

  # Fill from first date --> the FIRST dates will remain NA (if they were NA)
  filled_from_first_date <- na.locf(ts_obj, fromLast=FALSE)
  # Fill from last date --> the LAST dates will remain NA (if they were NA)
  filled_from_last_date <- na.locf(ts_obj, fromLast=TRUE)

  # replace value with NA if NA is found in one of the filled timeseries
  filled_from_first_date[is.na(filled_from_first_date) | is.na(filled_from_last_date)] <- NA
  return(filled_from_first_date)
}

test_matrix <- cbind(
  c(       1,        2,        3,        4,        5),
  c(      10,       NA,       NA,       40,       50),
  c(      NA,      200,      300,      400,      500),
  c(      NA,     2000,     3000,     4000,       NA),
  c(      NA,    20000,       NA,    40000,       NA),
  c(  100000,   200000,       NA,   400000,       NA),
  c( 1000000,  2000000,  3000000,  4000000,       NA),
  c(      NA,       NA, 30000000,       NA,       NA)
)
dates <- as.Date('2017-01-01') + 0:4
test_xts <- xts(test_matrix, dates)
print(test_xts)
result = fill_ts(test_xts)
print(result)

test_ts = as.timeSeries(test_xts)
result = fill_ts(test_ts)
print(result)
```

This function fills the (xts, timeSeries) timeseries and ignores trailing and leading NAs. The function is even rather quick - but still: This is a standard problem and I am sure, there is a standard (and hopefully more efficient) solution to it, that I didn't find.

Sorry, if this question was asked and answered 1000x ... I couldn't find an appropriate entry on stackoverflow.

Comment: I can't come up with an obviously better solution than yours.  I thought you might be able to do it with `na.fill`, since it can optionally leave the leading and trailing `NA`, but I couldn't figure out how to get the internal observations to be LOCF.

Comment: Just noticed the link to [na.locf but don't do trailing NAs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7296204/271616) in the list of related questions in the right-hand pane.  That solution works for this problem, so I'm marking this as a duplicate.

Comment: The linked issue is the perfect solution! It is 13x faster than my solution:

`    > dim(t)`
`     [1] 63230   209`
`    > system.time(na.approx(t, method="constant", na.rm=FALSE)`
`       user  system elapsed `
`      1.032   0.600   1.632 `
`    > system.time(fill_ts(t))`
`       user  system elapsed `
`     13.528   4.656  18.208`

So I withdraw my solution.